# How do I standardize only the numeric columns in a pandas dataframe efficiently

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

In a panda dataframe, I have nominal and real valued columns arbitrarily mixed and I want to standardize just the numeric columns. I have this piece of code, which does the job.. but it's using two .tolist() function calls to make it work. I had a hard time understanding indexing and I feel there might be a faster method to this

```
class Standardizer():
  def __init__(self, matrix):
    self.means_ = matrix.mean()
    self.stds_ = matrix.std()

  def transform(self, matrix):
    matrix = matrix.fillna(self.means_)

    matrix[self.means_.index] = (matrix[self.means_.index] - self.means_.tolist()) / self.stds_.tolist()

    return matrix
```